# Flash does not work when using front facing camera with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturedevice, ios-camera

I have a camera app that is using AVFoundation. When the user is taking a photo, they can press a button to toggle the flash on and off. Right now this works perfectly for the rear facing camera, but I cannot get it to work for the front facing camera.

No matter what I do, the front facing camera will not use a flash.

Here is the code I am using to toggle flash on and off on the button press:

```
-(IBAction)toggleFlash {

NSLog(@"Toggle flash button has been pressed");

NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
    if ([device hasFlash] == YES) {

        NSLog(@"Current Device Flash Mode: %d", device.flashMode);


        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];


        if(device.flashMode == 0) {

            [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];

            NSLog(@"New device flash mode: %d", device.flashMode);



        } else if (device.flashMode == 1) {

            [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];

            NSLog(@"New device flash mode: %d", device.flashMode);


        } else if (device.flashMode == 2) {

            [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];


        }

        [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
  }

}
```

Comment: Does the `AVCaptureDevice` for the front-facing camera actually return `YES` for `hasFlash`?  As far as I know, no iOS device has a front-facing flash.

Comment: @robmayoff Yeah it does, everything's contained in the code: if([device hasFlash] == YES) and it is successfully switching and NSLogging device.flashMode as "0" and then as "1" when you keep pressing the button.

Comment: Maybe it really doesn't have a flash. I guess I just assumed it would.

Comment: I'm 100 percent sure, that no iOS Device has a flash on front side.

Answer (score 1):

Although its an old thread, for anyone that currently want to "imitate" Flash on Front Camera with the switching white screen and is confused with the device's hasFlash property :

> The iPhone 6s and 6s Plus front-facing cameras are the first
>   front-facing iOS cameras to respond YES to the -hasFlash property.

Source : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21694 (Paragraph : Retina Flash)

Answer (score 0):

There is no iOS device with a flash on the front side. If it's like you said, that the `hasFlash` method returns `YES` for front-facing camera then this is a bug. Consider filing a [radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/) to Apple. You have the sample code that illustrates the issue so you can just attach it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you debugged correctly? If I'm running this shortened version of your code on my iPhone:

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Toggle flash button has been pressed");

    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    int i = 0;

    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices)
    {
        if ([device hasFlash] == YES)
            NSLog(@"Device %d has flash!", i);

        else
            NSLog(@"Device %d has no flash!", i);
        ++i;
    }

}
```

I get this result:

```
2014-03-08 09:45:48.551 test[12162:60b] Toggle flash button has been pressed
2014-03-08 09:45:48.597 test[12162:60b] Device 0 has flash!
2014-03-08 09:45:48.600 test[12162:60b] Device 1 has no flash!
```

So there's no front camera flash, and no bug by apple.